# PrimeFaces CRUD button take time to appear

Tags: performance, jsf, jpa, netbeans, primefaces

I am currently facing a performance issue for which I would like to have Your support please.

Here is my configuration:

> - NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
> - Primefaces 5.2
> - nbpfcrudgen-0.30.1-8.0.2_patch1-impl (CRUD Generator I used for my apps)
> - Glassfish 4.0 PostgreSQL 9.2

I created a crud apps with the Netbeans CRUD Generator (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbpfcrudgen/)

Below the code showing a list of Action in a table. At the bottom of the page there is a button “View” which is only activated when you select a row in the table.

Out of the box it is working perfectly fine: When I select a row the “View” button get activated in 2sc.

```
<h:form id="ActionListForm">
    <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListActionTitle}">
        <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                     value="#{actionController.items}"
                     var="item"
                     rowKey="#{item.idaction}"
                     paginator="true"
                     rows="10"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     selection="#{actionController.selected}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update=":ActionListForm:viewButton" listener="#{actionController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":ActionListForm:viewButton" listener="#{actionController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":ActionListForm:viewButton" listener="#{actionController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" onsuccess="document.getElementById('ActionListForm:viewButton').click();"/>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.idaction}" filterBy="#{item.idaction}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListActionTitle_idaction}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.idaction}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.actionlink}" filterBy="#{item.actionlink}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListActionTitle_actionlink}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.actionlink}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.identity.name}" filterBy="#{item.identity.name}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListActionTitle_identity}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.identity.name}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton id="viewButton"   style="visibility: hidden;" icon="ui-icon-search" value="#{bundle.View}" update=":ActionViewForm" oncomplete="PF('ActionViewDialog').show()" disabled="#{empty actionController.selected}"/>
</h:form>
```

Problems start when I tried to limit the record showed in the table, below my modification

```
<h:form id="ActionListForm">
    <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListActionTitle}">
        <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                     Value = "#budgetController.getAllActionByEntity('bob’}"
```

After this modification, when I select a row, the “View” button take at least 10sc to be activated. Below the getAllActionByEntity method in the class ActionController

```
public List<Action> getAllActionByEntity(String iduserparam) {
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("propensionPU");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  try {
      Entity identity = new Entity (iduserparam);
      allActionByEntity =  em.createNamedQuery("Action.findAllByEntity").setParameter("identity", identity).getResultList();
  }     
    catch (NoResultException e) {System.out.println (e);}
return allActionByEntity;
}
```

And the extract of Action.Java with the query referenced above:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Action.findAllByEntity", query = "SELECT a FROM Action a WHERE a.identity = :identity")})
```

Would anyone has an idea of the reason creating this slowness? In that case can you please help me to correct my mistake?

Comment: Warning: code generators usually don't produce efficient code. Only programmers are capable of writing efficient code.

Comment: Missing index? And why a jsf tag but no jpa one?

Comment: And offtopic: shouldn't you method be called `findAllByIdentity`

Comment: So you added the jpa tag, but did you do **any** profiling on where exactely the bottleneck is?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your help. Yes I followed your advice and add the JPA tag, fully agree it make sens. I am quite new in the coding area and not so familiar with profiling tool, I tried using the dev plugin in Firefox but without success. I would be really thank full if you could guide me to this kind of tools. I will try the index but I don't understand why the app would query the db just to activate a button. Anyway you advice really helps thanks.